# Libraries for inprocess perf profiling? (Intel performance counters on Linux)

Tags: linux, performance, perf

I want to profile an application's **critical path** by taking readings of the **performance counters** at various points along the path.

I came across [`libperf`](https://github.com/theonewolf/libperf) which provides a fairly neat C api. However, the last activity was 3 years ago.

I am also aware of the [`PAPI`](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/PAPI/). This is under active development.

- Are there other libraries I should be aware of?
- Can anyone offer any insight into using one or the other?
- Any tutorials / introductions to integrating these into application code?

Comment: Have you looked at valgrind?

Comment: @n.m. yes, but I want to be able to run this in production

Comment: I'm not sure why valgrind is different from any other profiler in this regard, but anyway. Yiu have mentioned Intel performance counters. Do you mean vtune? It exists on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I've used both PAPI (on Solaris) and perf (on Linux) and found it is much easier to record the entire program run and use 'perf-annotate' to see how your critical path is doing rather than trying to measure only the critical path. It's a different approach but it worked well for me.

Also, as someone mentioned at the comments, there is vTune, if you are x86 based. I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, among them:

- [JEvents](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools/tree/master/jevents)
- [libpfc](https://github.com/obilaniu/libpfc)
- [Intel PCM](https://github.com/opcm/pcm)
- [likwid](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid)
- Direct use of [`perf_event_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html)

I cover these in more detail in an [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45133491/149138).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor-a-better-way-to-measure-cpu-utilization?page=8

VTune however is proprietory, if you want it can serve the purpose. Try its 30 day trial.

perfmon and perfctr can be used for analysis of parts of program but will have to be included in the code itself.