# Why does clock_gettime return different values depending on how the function is timed?

Tags: c, linux, x86-64, benchmarking, timing

I'm trying to time a fast section of C code with `clock_gettime`. I'm roughly doing this

```c
struct timespec start, end1, end2;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start);
function_a();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &end1);
function_b();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &end2);

result1 = timespec_diff(&start, &end1);
result2 = timespec_diff(&start, &end2);
```

`result1` is around 130ns. `result2` is around 630ns. If I comment out `function_a`, `result1` goes to around 30ns, which is roughly the time taken by two consecutive `clock_gettime` calls. But `result2` only goes down to about 600ns.

`function_a` is a few control statements and pointer dereferences. Nothing crazy.
This is on an AMD EPYC CPU. I've run hundreds of warm up loops and averaged over millions of loops to get the numbers.

How could this happen? Why does `result1` have an extra 100ns?

Comment: You should almost always use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` for measurements.  The `RAW` variant is far to complicated to make use of.

Comment: What CPU are you running on?  Did you run a warm-up loop before this?  If not, typical x86 CPUs might be pausing their core clock briefly to change frequency to a higher boost clock.  That might be happening at a somewhat consistent point in your whole program's run-time.

Comment: Not to mention you are not running in a real-time environment, even if running a RT kernel as task switching and whatever else your computer may be doing at the time will effect your measurements, especially down in the ns weeds.

Comment: I collected some descriptions. It's a C++ library but the descriptions are language agnostic:
https://github.com/TedLyngmo/CloCXX/blob/main/seen_clockid_t

Comment: @PeterCordes this is on an AMD EPYC CPU. I've run hundreds of warm up loops and averaged over millions of loops to get the numbers

How can I verify the clock frequency change?

Comment: @TedLyngmo why is `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` better? From the documentation, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is affected by NTP changes but `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` is not. Doesn't that make ``CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` better?

Comment: @abattleofwords: If you already have warm-up loops then that probably doesn't explain it.  One way would be to compare `rdtsc` (which doesn't stop ticking while the core clock is stopped) against HW performance events (with `rdpmc` from user-space, after the kernel programs it to count an event like `cpu_clk_unhalted.ref_tsc` (same rate as RDTSC but *does* halt when the core clock halts).  Or just count in `cycles` and take CPU frequency out of the picture to see what happens.)

Comment: See [Lost Cycles on Intel? An inconsistency between rdtsc and CPU\_CLK\_UNHALTED.REF\_TSC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45472147) for the details on one Intel CPU of how long the core clock halts while stabilizing a new frequency/voltage.  Anyway, `_mm_lfence(); start_tsc = __rdtsc();` might be a way to get a second measurement of `clock_gettime` times.  [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86\_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13772567)

Comment: @PeterCordes Where would you place that in relatation to `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: How would I order / sequence `__rdtsc()` or `__rdtscp(&dummy)` in relation to `clock_gettime`?  Depends what you want to measure, I guess.  It's somewhat lighter weight than `clock_gettime` (which on x86-64 Linux will itself use `rdtsc` in the VDSO code, with scale factors as an offset from the last tick of the `_COARSE` clock also read from the VDSO data). But far from free, like 20 to 30 cycles throughput cost, so maybe 5 ns.  Anyway, I might set `start_tsc` before the first `clock_gettime`, and then record another timestamp before, after, or both for the second `clock_gettime`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: You could try sprinkling `lfence; rdtsc; lfence` before and after every `clock_gettime`.  If the timing discrepancy is still reproducible with that, then you have a second more detailed set of measurements using a different scale but also linear with wall-clock time.  If not, then different runs with `rdtsc` at different points, and hope that fewer measurements disturbs the experiment less.

Comment: @PeterCordes My question may have sounded like something it was not intented to sound like. The hardware, semi-soft and soft clocks I've collected could do with your very platform dependent clock, provided I understand how to describe it properly.

Comment: @PeterCordes That is, I'm not questioning your comment. I'm in integration-mode and would like to add the clock for platforms where it works.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Were you asking how I'd compare `_mm_lfence(); __rdtsc` vs. `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` or `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`?  That was the other possibility.  IDK, I've rarely used either.  If I want to microbenchmark something, I put it in a loop to measure either its throughput or latency, preferably in a static executable that does nothing else, so I can run `perf stat` on the whole process and get time (task-clock) and `cycles`, and also instruction, instructions-per-cycle, uops, cache misses, etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: For things on the scale of a CPU's out-of-order exec window (the ROB or PRF capacity, and scheduler size for unexecuted uops), like a few hundred insns, timing overhead and draining the pipeline around the thing I'm timing is not realistic.  The OP's 100 ns function is barely longer than one out-of-order exec window, depending on IPC, on a modern EPYC.  (https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/05/amds-zen-4-part-1-frontend-and-execution-engine/ - Zen 4 ROB size is 320 uops, up from 256 in Zen 3.  At 5 uops per cycle front-end bandwidth, as short as 64 cycles best case (16 ns at 4GHz)

Comment: @PeterCordes _"Were you asking..."_ - No, sorry, the question was meant to generate (steal) a description (from you) of what I could put in the generated C++ clock's description (provided it can be generated at all).  If what you describe is something you do to measure and compare regularly, it sounds like a clock I could add and give a name. If anything, it could provide a common base for people throwing numbers around, which I like.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: The TSC frequency depends on the CPU, but not necessarily in a way that depends on the frequency of the actual cores, so it's the absolute opposite of anything that's useful to compare between different people's CPUs if they don't measure  the actual TSC frequency on their CPU.  e.g. 4008 MHz on my i7-6700k which has a "stock" frequency of 4000 MHz, but for single-threaded code runs at its max turbo of 4200 MHz if I have EPP=performance.  Otherwise at 3900 MHz, or lower if it downclocks for memory-bound code.  Low-power CPUs have TSC farther from max turbo, and sometimes from stack

Comment: @TedLyngmo TSC is basically equivalent to wall-clock time or presumably MONOTONIC_RAW at least over short intervals, but you have to manually scale back to seconds.  It definitely doesn't change scale factors during a measurement according to any NTP stuff, just the free running raw hardware clock.  Which sounds sensible to me for timing; If there is a reason to avoid `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` for benchmarking / interval-timing purposes, your links didn't make it clear to me.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: HW performance counters (e.g. `cycles` aka `cpu_clk_unhalted.thread` on Intel) *are* highly useful, but [it's non-trivial to set things up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45123524) so you can use `rdpmc` from user-space to read the right counter; something (like `perf`) has to have programmed the counters and you have to know which counter index to put in ECX.  That is the lowest-overhead way to time an interval on x86; it's a faster instruction than `rdtsc`.  (Although like `rdtsc`, I think you'd want to use it with `lfence`)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: [clflush to invalidate cache line via C function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51818655) shows use of `lfence` and `rdtsc` to get consistent measurements over short intervals for a cache-miss load.  Measurement is consistent, and lower than `clock_gettime`.  `lfence` controls out-of-order exec around the time measurement; IDK what `clock_gettime` does.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's the non-trivial part that makes me think it may be worth some effort. It'll fall apart if each use-case must be hand-tweaked though, so perhaps I'm aiming for a bigger bite than I can chew.  It certainly would very nice to put at least some percentage of your xp into something others could use and compare (with the platform specifics clearly stated) though. A `clock<platformX>` wouldn't be convertible to a `clock<platformY>`. I'll see if I can find a better motivation for avoiding `RAW` and return with that later. Bedtime :-)

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh what bad memory I have :-) I now remember gettting the idea to nearly never use the `RAW` variant after feedback to my [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286738/stdchrono-compatible-clock-using-clock-monotonic-raw). Perhaps I came to the wrong conclusion? Edit: I see that one ended up as a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOXG3zD8rhU) too :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I guess it might be possible to define a `clock<HW_CORE_CLOCKS>` that used `perf_event_open` for the `cycles` event.  But you'd want to do `perf_event_open` before the timed region, since that's high overhead.  You want the start and stop to just be `rdpmc`, so you'd want maybe a static singleton responsible for starting that when the process starts.  Allowing user-space `rdpmc` is something that might need root to change some `/proc` files, I forget.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Ah yes, that codereview Q&A.  I suspect that variations in `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` would be correlated with (and thus cancel out) variations in the actual core clock frequency, if they're derived from the same oscillator.  So for microbenchmarking I'd prefer `RAW`, or bare `rdtscp` and scale it later, if I wanted to time intervals.